# Loop and List in Python

Tags: python-3.8

With below code, I was expecting to swap two lists and was expecting all the elements from 'names' list to 'Excluded_list'using Pop() function. But it is not working expectedly, can someone please tell the issue with below code ??

```py
names=['Ram','Sham','Mohan','John','Kuldeep']
Excluded_list=[]
print('names list',names)
print('Excluded list ',Excluded_list)
```

Code to swap/reprint lists

```py
for name in names:
    Excluded_list.append(names.pop())
print('names list',names)
print('Excluded list ',Excluded_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying "names" in the for-loop, which means that the "for name in names" does not evaluate as you expect.

Replace the for-loop with a while-loop.

```
while len(names):
    Excluded_list.append(names.pop())
```

Comment: Thanks Kim, It really helped. But I am still confused over For loop failure, If possible can you please explain why it fails??

Comment: You should not modify the list (here names) you are iterating over. This is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/8450075)

Comment: Got it now .Thanks a lot !!